# Save scroll state in nested RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-view, android-scrollview

I have a problem in my application. I have main list (recycler view). This list keeps 20 horizontal recycler views. It looks really similar like Netflix app. I need to keep state of every "carousel" in main list. If I move first item to right, next to left, scroll down (first and second items are recycled), rotate the screen, scroll up, I need to have restored position of first and second element.

I know that I should use linearLayout.saveOnInstanceState and onRestoreState but my problem is that every carousel is in main list.

`configChanges` in AndroidManifest.xml can not come into play...

Thank you!

Comment: You could use this library to save a scroll state for Nested RecyclerView https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can save `scrollX` position when you item of `RecyclerView` is being recycled, and then scroll that much when that item is being bind again:

```
int[] scrollXState = new int[20]; // assuming there are 20 carousel items

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // setup recycler here, then post scrollX after recycler has been laid out
    holder.nestedRecyclerView.post(() ->
            holder.nestedRecyclerView.setScrollX(scrollXState[holder.getAdapterPosition()]));
}

@Override
public void onViewRecycled(MyViewHolder holder) {
    scrollXState[holder.getAdapterPosition()] = holder.nestedRecyclerView.getScrollX();
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    RecyclerView nestedRecyclerView;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
```

Only thing you should take care of is that you do not want parent adapter to be destroyed and created after orientation change, make it survive orientation change. Otherwise save `int[]` into `Bundle` and then get it back from `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Comment: Ok, Your answer makes sense. Even if os kills activity with view I can restore `int[]` from bundle :)

Comment: `scrollX` / `getScrollX()` from a (yes, horizontally scrolling) recycler view is always 0.

Comment: @Ixx, that's weird.

Comment: I think we have to use `computeHorizontalScrollOffset()`

Answer (score 14):

As @Ixx mentioned scrollX is always 0. You have to use layoutManager to save and restore scroll position

```
 val scrollStates = mutableMapOf<Int, Parcelable?>()
override fun onViewRecycled(holder: VH) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder)

    val key = holder.layoutPosition
    scrollStates[key] = holder.childRecycler.layoutManager.onSaveInstanceState()
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VH, position: Int) {
    val key = holder.layoutPosition
    val state = scrollStates[key]
    if(state != null){
        holder.childRecycler.layoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(state)
    }else{

        holder.childRecycler.layoutManager.scrollToPosition(0)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but I can save the state only once. Then the value never changes. It's always the same scroll offset. You happen to know why?

Comment: OMG. I can't believe this worked. I've been dealing with this problem for weeks. I don't know how to thank you. That's the best way to save the position for child recyclerView.
I just removed the else condition at the end because it was moving the scroll to the starting point on the first recycle. 
Again thank you so much. You saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution i implemented:

1:Use layout manager to find the lastVisible element by using `recyclerView.layoutmanager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()`

2. use an interface to send this value to your calling activity or fragment
3. store this value in a hashmap and pass it to the outer recyclerViewAdapter
4. pass it to the inner recyclerViewAdapter to update it to the position stored by using `recyclerview.scrollToPosition[hashmapofpositions[YOUR_KEY]]`

This way your state that you used in the last run is conserved.